# How to check if App is installed when someone click on my shared Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, share

I have a code to share Data using `Intent`. Suppose After sharing something to FB when somebody clicks on that it should check if that app is installed in that user's phone if yes then it should open particular activity from app and if not it should redirect to link to download app.

My Code is as below:

```
  btnShareData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                isAppInstalled("co.AppName");
                imageUri = getResources().getString(R.string.share_data_url) + data.getId();
                Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
                sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, data.getTitle());
                sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, imageUri);
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent,  "Share Via..."));
        }

    });



public boolean isAppInstalled(String packageName) {
        try {
            getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(packageName, 0);
            return true;
        }
        catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(getResources().getString(R.string.app_download))));
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I've looked for other answers and implemented this but it's not working. After sharing it on my FB wall if I click on that it's just open `share_data_url` link in browser.

Comment: You will not be able to intercept click in other applications(FB etc).

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use **firebase dynamic link**. Have a try and if you have any doubt feel free to ask.

Comment: Do I have to add project on Firebase first? Any other alternative solutions for this?

Comment: Yes, It's very easy to add your project in firebase. This way you can use firebase features.  Just try it. Have any doubt belongs to this?

Comment: For referring to apps for IOS/Android behavior we must have to have app in app store but our app is still in development. It’s not available in play store. Also any other alternative if we do not want to add our project on firebase?

Comment: For android other option is to use intent filters by creating deep links to the app. Please go through documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking). But as of my understanding, some devices won't completely support this, because of custom browsers.